# JQuery UI without image files

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to create a fully self-contained page which uses JQuery UI components, namely datepicker and slider. "Self-contained" meaning no use of files except for .html itself, including images. CSS and JS are not a problem, since they can go inside `<style>` and `<script>` tags.

Obviously I can't get rounded corners, etc. but I don't care about that: just something which looks acceptable. Is it possible?

Comment: when you say external, do you mean from a third party CDN or just you don't want any images?

Comment: @TimBJames Any images, I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely possible.

If you take a copy of the jQuery UI library and CSS file, but NOT the images, then everything works. Although it does lack all the Icons.

You would need to hack the javascript code in order to substitute any icons with text. e.g. a right arrow could become `>`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't use images for rounded corners. As long as you are using a CSS3 compatible browser, you can use rounded corners.

As for the icons, some icons are somewhat integral to the function of the widget, so you might run into issues there (eg datepicker). Is it possible to not incluse the icon image files? Yes. Will you run in to some unintended side effects? Yes.